# SqlTransaction not committing - C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions

I am using `SqlTransaction` for updating data from a DataTable to a SQL Server table.

The code is working great without any errors. But changes aren't reflected in the table for some reason. Not a single error encountered.

Below is my C# code (not entire code)

```
using (con)
{
    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed || con.State == ConnectionState.Broken)
        con.Open();

    using (SqlTransaction trans = con.BeginTransaction())
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCommand, con, trans))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                SqlCommandBuilder cmb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);

                da.InsertCommand = cmb.GetInsertCommand();
                da.UpdateCommand = cmb.GetUpdateCommand();
                // da.DeleteCommand = cmb.GetDeleteCommand(); 

                da.InsertCommand.Transaction = trans;
                da.UpdateCommand.Transaction = trans;

                da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;

                da.Fill(sourceDt);

                if (sb.Length > 0)
                {
                    trans.Rollback();
                    throw new Exception(sb.ToString());
                }

                sourceDt.Merge(clonedDt, false, MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey);

                try
                {
                    noOfRowsAffected = da.Update(sourceDt);
                    trans.Commit();    // Commit the changes to database
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                { }

                if (noOfRowsAffected > 0)
                { 
                    Boolean success = true; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please mark changes if I am missing anything.

Comment: What is the scope of `trans` and how is it being constructed?

Comment: Hello @DanWilson, I have updated the code in the post. the trans is within the scope.

Comment: You are missing an opening { after the third using. Is that a typo just here or in your code?

Comment: You should get the same results if you remove the transaction, that is to say, I postulate the transaction is a red herring and it committing or not is not the issue.

Comment: sorry guys, it was just typo. I have edited the code with exact code in my project.There are no red  error lines

Comment: @JeroenMostert sorry I did not understand, should I remove the transaction?

Comment: You could try for testing purposes. If the table remains empty, you know the presence or absence of the transaction is not the issue. (In production, you probably want the transaction to ensure all changes happen or none do.) ... before you do any of that, though, *remove the exception handler that masks all errors*.

Comment: Are you sure your code isn't getting into that empty `catch` when you update the table?

Comment: No, does not enter in catch @JoshPart

Comment: @JoshPart even after removing trans, there are no errors but still not updating.